# etnaviv : IMX6 Solo GPU Performance Issue With OpenGL ES-CM 1.1

Tags: gpu, x11, xorg, imx6, opengl-es-1.1

We have an IMX6 solo custom device running with WinCE7 & Linux on it

We have developed a custom benchmark application using OpenGL ES-CM 1.1

When I ran the benchmark application on WinCE7 the performance looked good but with similar application on Linux gave 50 % reduction in performance.

Following is our configuration

```
Linux       - Mainline 5.15
GPU driver  - Etnaviv
X Driver    - xf86-video-armada
OpenGL      - OpenGL ES-CM 1.1
```

WinCE Result:

```
EGL version : 1.4
GL vendor   : Vivante Corporation
GL renderer : Vivante GC880
GL version  : OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 Mesa 22.0.3
 
run scene 'Floating Frame3D VBO'
initialize, DATA_SIZE:11264, No of Frames:512 Average FPS = 48.075005
---
 
run scene 'Floating Frame3D'
initialize, DATA_SIZE:11264, No of Frames:512 Average FPS = 31.975005
---
 
run scene 'Frame 3D Fixed'
initialize, DATA_SIZE:11264, No of Frames:512 Average FPS = 31.505484
---
 
run scene 'Floating graph'
Average FPS = 238.403093
---
 
run scene 'Fixed graph'
Average FPS = 238.187271


Linux result:

EGL version : 1.4
GL vendor   : etnaviv
GL renderer : Vivante GC880 rev 5106
GL version  : OpenGL ES-CM 1.1 Mesa 22.0.3
 
run scene 'Floating Frame3D VBO'
initialize, DATA_SIZE:11264, No of Frames:512 Average FPS = 26.872623
---
 
run scene 'Floating Frame3D'
initialize, DATA_SIZE:11264, No of Frames:512 Average FPS = 24.373300
---
 
run scene 'Frame 3D Fixed'
initialize, DATA_SIZE:11264, No of Frames:512 Average FPS = 23.783205
---
 
run scene 'Floating graph'
Average FPS = 136.624447
---
 
run scene 'Fixed graph'
Average FPS = 136.510016
```

glmark2 which uses opengl 2.2 gives 80 % score. Can it be issue with OpenGl 1.1 ? Or X driver?

At the moment not able to figure out where is the problem.  Any help is appreciable.